# Cloning a DIV with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following Javascript:

```
$("div.duplicate-fields:last-child").clone().find('input').each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']'});
    this.value = "";
    this.checked = false;
}).removeClass("active").end().appendTo("#duplicate-section");
```

Inside a `.click()` function.  This works fine.  However I have the following HTML in the cloned area:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons"><label class="btn btn-default button-array "><input type="checkbox" name="select-sessions[3][1]" value="">Session 1</label>
<label class="btn btn-default button-array "><input type="checkbox" name="select-sessions[3][2]" value="">Session 2</label>
<label class="btn btn-default button-array "><input type="checkbox" name="select-sessions[3][3]" value="">Session 3</label>
<label class="btn btn-default button-array "><input type="checkbox" name="select-sessions[3][4]" value="">Session 4</label>
<label class="btn btn-default button-array active"><input type="checkbox" name="select-sessions[3][5]" checked="" value="">Session 5</label>
</div>
```

Now, in the above jQuery I have `this.checked=false;` which makes any cloned checkbox unchecked.  But unfortunately, The `label.button-array` still has the class of `active`, which means it still looks like it is checked.

So I modified my jQuery function be like this:

```
$("div.duplicate-fields:last-child").clone().find('input').each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']'});
    this.value = "";
    this.checked = false;
}).find("label.button-array.active").each(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
}).end().appendTo("#duplicate-section");
```

Notice the new `find()` function added on to the first.  However, It seems to completely remove all the HTML from the clone, and I end up with a few input boxes and that's about it.  I cannot figure out why.

In this image you can see the first cloned area, and then after pressing the button (with the new `find()` function added in, as shown above):

[image: I just end up with raw input fields]

Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle with problems like you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `.end()`.

So you were operating on the first selection (input), which means instead of appending the cloned div.duplicate-fields to #duplicate-section, you were instead appending your collection of inputs to #duplicate-section (which explains the five checkboxes)

Try replacing your second block with this

```
$("div.duplicate-fields:last-child").clone().find('input').each(function () {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/, function (str, p1) { return '[' + (parseInt(p1, 10) + 1) + ']' });
    this.value = "";
    this.checked = false;
}).end().find("label.button-array.active").each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
}).end().appendTo("#duplicate-section");
```

---

Bootply - http://www.bootply.com/bPwHVfFzK8

Comment: This works, and also explains why my first attempt didnt work.  I suspected I needed something like this but I didn't have enough knowledge about `find()` to do it.  Thank you!

Comment: It would be lovely if you could explain the image above too, and why I was getting those results?

Comment: Done (2nd para), let me know if it isn't clear. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
$("div.duplicate-fields:last-child").clone().find('input').each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']'});
    this.value = "";
    this.checked = false;
    $(this).parent("label.button-array.active").removeClass("active");
}).removeClass("active").end().appendTo("#duplicate-section");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already looping each input element, you can try to use $.parent() to get the label, then edit its class.

Something like

```
$("div.duplicate-fields:last-child").clone().find('input').each(function() {
    this.name = this.name.replace(/\[(\d+)\]/,function(str,p1){return '[' + (parseInt(p1,10)+1) + ']'});
    this.value = "";
    this.checked = false;
    $(this).parent().removeClass("active");
}).end().appendTo("#duplicate-section");
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well.  I haven't marked it as the answer because it didn't explain why it was happening.  But thank you so much for your help.